# Fatal errors are coming after i run static-content:deploy with third party theme

Tags: magento2, theme, fatal-error, core

I am facing some strange issues in Magento 2.1.3, i have configured third party theme and working fine, once i run `setup:static-content:deploy`, am getting fatal errors like i added below from core code. if we solve one error then it is throwing other errors.

I found same issues [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3963) **MAGETWO-51440**, even my code had the changes.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   ReflectionParameter::isArray() in
>    \vendor\magento\framework\Code\Generator\EntityAbstract.php:324

Can any one help me on this strange issue.

Comment: Which is your application mode?

Comment: @Khoa TruongDinh , Current application mode is default.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a problem with the theme?

I would also try running in developer mode as this will generate the files on demand, and try deleting `pub/static/frontend` and `var/view_preprocessed`.

Comment: We are running the application in multiple local systems, there the same theme is working fine. We are facing this issue when we deploy static content alot. As I added MAGETWO-51440 link in the question

Comment: All I can suggest is deleting var/generation, var/cache and var/di. If that doesn't work it could be related to sample data if you have that installed? Other than that I'm out of ideas sorry.

Comment: I have removed the files and tested but no luck, yes I have my local application  with sampledata. @Ben, Inputs are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Damn it, apologies I can't help more.

Comment: Glad your response on my question. Will try in few more ways. Thank you so mush. Please reach me Linked in : krisnaijjada.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Then after that deploy static contents.

I think this happens when more than one entities tried to modify the same file(s) including the databases. I don't know for sure. but doing this fixed the error for me.
Alternatively you can do the complete steps,

```
setup:upgrade
setup:di:compile
setup:static-content:deploy
indexer:reindex

cache:clean
```

is optional.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/104378)

Comment: i had the same issue. and doing as I said fixed it

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: @MohamedSaleh before running compile command, remove the content in var and pub->static director. **(rather than removing them, you can compress files intoa zipped file and keep it as a backup)**

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command stem wise

```
rm-rf var/*
rm-rf pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
chmod -R 777 pub/static/ var/
```

it will help you